# Kio estas la diferenco inter scivola kaj scivolema?

Tags: word-meaning

Mi preskaŭ ĉiam aŭdas *scivolema*, sed nun iu demandis min se oni ne povas simple diri *scivola*. 
Mi pensas ke la *-ema* estas bona, sed kio fakte estas la diferenco inter la du vortoj?

Ekzemplo:

- Mi estas scivolema. Mi volas scii ĉion pri tio.
- Mi estas scivola. Mi volas scii ĉion pri tio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uzu *scivola* aŭ *scivoli* kiam temas pri sola afero, kaj *scivolema* por priskribi personecon.

Ekzemple:

> Mi scivolas pri via libro.
>
> Kio estas tio? Mi scivolas.
>
> Ŝi estas scivolema knabino.
>
> Mi demandas multe pro tio ke mi estas scivolema.

Answer (score 11):

Certe kelkaj personoj miksas la du signifojn, sed ĝenerale, scivola estas portempa afero.

- vi ja ne povas kaŝi, ke vi estas iom scivola.

Kaj *scivolema* estas pli malpli konstanta trajto:

- Alico [estas] afabla, bonkora, scivolema knabino.

Ankaŭ okuloj, rigardoj, kaj vizaĝoj povas esti scivolaj.

Comment: Mi pensas ke ili estas komencantoj, kiel mi.   Dankegon pro la bona respondo!